# How to parse a link for images, videos to use in web app, like how Facebook does?

Tags: php, facebook

I'm wondering how sites like Facebook, and I'm assuming Pinterest does this too (I haven't used it) scan and parse links for images and videos, and then fetch those rich media files to display on your wall. I want to experiment with implementing this in my own app which is in PHP. Right now I'm guessing it is done with a combination of JavaScript/ajax and PHP?  I also wonder if the Snoopy PHP class is something that could be used?for any answers.

Comment: You have a lot to read up on my friend. Facebook is a massive ajax-based site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is combination of javascript/ajax and PHP.

Actually, when Facebook's javascript detects a link in a textarea, it sends an ajax request to the Facebook's server. This called script works as a proxy and downloads all important data about the specified page, parses meta tags and returns informations like description and image to the client, which shows the informations even before the story is submitted.

When you post a story to wall, these (cached) informations are parsed again and are being saved in their database.

Comment: Hmm.. I think this answer isn't an answer to the question asked.

Comment: @Stewie: I said everything OP need to know in order to reproduce Facebook's method. I do not know any Snoopy class. OP asked how is it being done and `Right now I'm guessing it is done with a combination of javascript/ajax and php?`

Answer (score 0):

Read link, fetch the contents of the page, go to the `<body>` tag, read the `<img>` tags. 
For the description, read the `<meta>` tags OR the `<h>` tags in the body

Comment: Hmm.. I think this answer is really just ... a summary

Comment: so how can this be an answer?